# Different layout with different screen size with bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to achieve 2 different layouts for the same content with bootstrap 3. Let's say I have div1 orange, div2 blue and div3 green. Is it possible to arrange them as on screenshot so in the 2nd layout the green div will be in same row as orange div?

[image: Mobile Phone layout]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this..

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 one">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 two pull-right">2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 three pull-left">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/109690

Comment: Skelly you rock! I was playing with col-sm-push/pull and it didn't work. Thanks!